# Trigonometric problem in solving a PDE

Tags: trigonometry, partial-differential-equations

I'm self-studying partial differential equations with course material from 2018 and I have example solutions to the exercises. I have tried to arrive at the example solution for this PDE already a few days without success. Is there an error in the solution or am I mising something? The given PDE is

$\begin{cases} yu_x-4xu_y=2xy \\ u(x,x^2)=1\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} x'=y\\y'=-4x \end{cases}\implies\begin{cases} x=c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t)\\y=2c_2\cos(2t)-2c_1\sin(2t). \end{cases}$

By some basic trigonometric identities

$z'=2xy=4c_1c_2\cos(4t)+2(c_2^2-c_1^2)\sin(4t)\implies z=c_1c_2\sin(4t)+\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2-c_2^2)\cos(4t)+c.$

The solutions claim that $z=c+(c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t))^2=c+x^2.$ The 'middle component' of $x^2$ seems to really be there, but $\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2-c_2^2)\cos(4t)+c$ does not fit.

UPDATE: I omitted this, because I thought that people used to solving PDE's would understand what is going on and I simply wanted to know how can I arrive at this example solution instead of the one I calculated. I thought that it would be a case of using some trigonometric identity I missed. Here is the example solution. It involves using a curve, $\beta(s)=(x(s),y(s))=(s,s^2)$ and $z(t)=u(x(t),y(t))$.

$\begin{cases} x(0,s)=c_1=s\\y(0,s)=2c_2=s^2\\z(0,s)=c+s^2=1\end{cases}\implies \begin{cases} x(t,s)=s\cos(2t)+\frac{1}{2}s^2\sin(2t)\\y(t,s)=s^2\cos(2t)-2s\sin(2t)\\z(t,s)=1-s^2+x^2\end{cases}$

I'm confused about the $z$ (course material states that $z$ is $u$ along a 'characteristic curve'), because I do not know how it is calculated from the question. The material does not say anything about Charpit-Lagrange, only integration is used. After finding the correct $z$, the procedure taught in the material continues by calculating $s$ and $t$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ and then substituting them to $z$, giving $u(x,y)$. In this case, according to the example, 'only $s^2$ needs to be solved' (there's only $s^2$ in $z$, no $t$ or $s$) and it can be obtained from the equation $4x^2+y^2=4s^2+s^4$ to arrive at $u(x,y)=3+x^2-\sqrt{4x^2+y^2+4}$ which is the same answer JJacquelin gives by using Charpit-Lagrange.

Can anyone can tell me how to get the example solution with direct integration of $z'$? Or that it cannot be done?

UPDATE 2: eyeballfrog tells that

$c_1c_2\sin(4t) + \frac{1}{2}(c_1^2+c_2^2)+\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2-c_2^2)\cos(4t)=x^2$. So $\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2+c_2^2)+\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2-c_2^2)\cos(4t)=c_1^2\cos^2(2t)+c_2^2\sin^2(2t)$.

I cannot see how. Using $\cos(4t)=\cos(2t+2t)=\cos^2(2t)-\sin^2(2t)$ I get

$\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2-c_2^2)\cos(4t)=\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2\cos^2(2t)-c_1^2\sin^2(2t)-c_2^2\cos^2(2t)+c_2^2\sin^2(2t))=\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2-c_2^2)\cos^2(2t)+\frac{1}{2}(c_2^2-c_1^2)\sin^2(2t)$.

Adding eyeballfrog's constant $\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2+c_2^2)$ should somehow transfrom $\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2-c_2^2)$ to $c_1^2$ and $\frac{1}{2}(c_2^2-c_1^2)$ to $c_2^2$. LAST EDIT: eyballfrog posted an answer, I had the wrong identity.

Comment: Did you back substitute in order to verify both the solutions?

Comment: What is $z$? Where did that appear in the question and why did it suddenly appear in your solution?

Comment: @BenjaminWang $z$ is $u$ along a 'characteristic curve’. See the comment in JJacquelin's answer and the updated question.

Comment: By some more basic trig identities, $$[c_1 \cos(2t) + c_2\sin(2t)]^2 = c_1^2\cos^2(2t) + 2c_1c_2\sin(2t)\cos(2t) + c_2^2\sin^2(2t) \\= c_1c_2\sin(4t) + (c_1^2+c_2^2)/2 + (c_1^2 - c_2^2)/2 \cos(4t)$$. The constant term $(c_1^2+c_2^2)/2$ can then be folded into the arbitrary constant $c$. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, but I want to know the identities, too. I tried quite a few times. Could you write it out as an answer? And, if possible, also include how to solve for $s^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sine double-angle identity gives
$$
2\sin x\cos x = \sin(2x)
$$
and the half-angle identities give
$$
\sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\;\;\;;\;\;\;\cos^2 x = \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}
$$
Using these together gives
$$
[c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t)]^2 + C = c_1c_2\sin(4t) + \frac{c_1^2-c_2^2}{2}\cos(4t) + \frac{c_1^2+c_2^2}{2} + C.
$$
Since $C$ is an arbitrary real number, $C + (c_1^2+c_2^2)/2$ is just as arbitrary, so $z = x^2 + C$ and $z = c_1c_2\sin(4t) + \frac{c_1^2-c_2^2}{2}\cos(4t) + C$ are equivalent.

As for the second part, there's really no getting around the back-substitution to match points $(x,y)$ to the intersection of their characteristic with the boundary condition. The integration of $z'$ only gives you $z$'s dependence on $t$. The dependence on $s$ has to be found through other means.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll read through and understand your solution after I have taken a break (and accept it as the answer). I was stuck with the wrong identity for this task, it looked like a close shot and I thought maybe I just had some mistake there (update 2 in the question).

Answer (score 1):

First comment :

Your solution (expressed on parametric form) :
$$\begin{cases} 
x=c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t)\\
y=2c_2\cos(2t)-2c_1\sin(2t)\\
u=c_1c_2\sin(4t)+\frac{1}{2}(c_1^2-c_2^2)\cos(4t)+c 
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad u(x,y)=\frac12 x^2-\frac18 y^2+c$$
satisfies the PDE but doesn't satisfies the condition $u(x,x^2)=1$.

In fact you correctly found a set of solutions but not all solutions. And among this incomplete set of solutions no one satisfies the condition.

Second comment :

You wrote : However, the solutions claim that $z=c+(c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t))^2.$

This is not a correct manner to wrote what is claimed. You should have writen :

However, the solutions claim that
$$\begin{cases} 
x= \text{ a function of t }\\
y= \text{ a function of t }\\
z=c+(c_1\cos(2t)+c_2\sin(2t))^2. 
\end{cases}$$
One cannot take for granted that you use the same parameter as the parameter used in the reference book.

As the question is presently raised one cannot compare your result to the reference book result.

In addition, another approch not parametric :
$$yu_x-4xu_y=2xy$$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-4x}=\frac{du}{2xy}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{-4x}$
$$4x^2+y^2=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{-4x}=\frac{du}{2xy}$
$$u+\frac14 y^2=c_2$$
Don't confuse the notations $c_1$ , $c_2$ with the notations used above.

The general solution of the PDE (without taking account of a boundary condition)  expressed on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is : $\quad u+\frac14 y^2=F(4x^2+y^2)\quad$ where $F$ is an arfitrary function.
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=-\frac14 y^2+F(4x^2+y^2)}$$
CONDITION : $u(x,x^2)=1$
$$-\frac14 (x^2)^2+F(4x^2+(x^2)^2)=1$$
$$F(4x^2+x^4)=1+\frac14 x^4$$
Let $X=4x^2+x^4 \quad\implies\quad x^2=-2+\sqrt{4+X}$
$$F(X)=1+\frac14 \left(-2+\sqrt{4+X}\right)^2$$
Now the function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=4x^2+y^2$
$$u(x,y)=-\frac14 y^2+1+\frac14 \left(-2+\sqrt{4+(4x^2+y^2)}\right)^2$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=3+x^2-\sqrt{4+4x^2+y^2}}$$
This is the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition.

Comment: You are right, I should have included also $x$ and $y$ with $z$ in my solution. I omitted them, because my $z$ seems to be wrong. Then from the $x$ and $y$ I could solve $s$ and/or $t$ and substitute them to $z$, thus obtaining a function of $x$ and $y$. That's what the course material has taught this far on solving this kind of problems. I edited the question.

Comment: This is OK after you updated the question. Now your result is consistent with my result.

Comment: Is it possible to get the result $z=c+x^2$ by direct integration of $z'$? I still have no clue how that is obtained.

Comment: $u(x,y)=c+x^2$ is an obvious particular solution of the PDE. But it doesn't satisfies the condition $u(x,x^2)=1$. One can found it by direct integration of the PDE in the particular case $u_y=0$ (if you are looking for solutions independant of $y$). This particular solution belongs to the general solution with $F(X)=\frac{X}{4}+c$. I cannot see what you want to do with it.